# JavaFX app with SOAP communication. Is it possible?

Tags: java, web-services, soap, javafx, javafx-8

I am new to JavaFX and SOAP. I want to make JavaFX app that will be able to receive XML files using SOAP.

I only found this link: http://abhisarswami.blogspot.sk/2009/05/soap-request-from-javafx.html

Unfortunately that tutorial is for JavaFX 1.0, that means .fx script files which aren't supported in newer versions.

Is it possible to do it? Does anybody have any useful articles, advices or code snippets?

Comment: The two things are really completely independent. Write your class or classes that do the soap communication, process the XML files they receive, and create objects representing your data. Then write the JavaFX UI that display the data. You should basically be able to switch between Swing and JavaFX or any other UI mechanism you want to use without changing the SOAP communication code, and change between SOAP or JDBC or any other data access without changing your UI code. The reason you can't find any documentation on the two together is most likely because they are unrelated topics.

Comment: OK, I haven't tried to do any app with soap. I will do that firstly and then I will try to merge it with java-fx. Thanks, I thought that it is a problem.

Comment: [Here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/javafxinteg-2062777.html) is a very good general overview of JavaFX integration strategies; it doesn't really address SOAP directly but the basic ideas might be useful. It is a fairly advanced treatment.